# uniqueness of antiderivative up to constants

Tags: calculus, derivatives

**Statement:** Let $[a.b]$ be a compact interval of positive length, and let $f,g:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable functions. Show that $f'(x) = g'(x)$ for every $x\in [a,b]$ if and only if $f(x) = g(x)+C$ for some constant $C\in \mathbb{R}$ and all $x\in [a,b]$.

The "if" part is trivial  from the definition of derivative, but I wonder if there is a simple way to show the "only if" part. This is a remark from my graduate analysis note, I am probably overthinking about this problem.

**Proof:** To show that 
$$f'(x) = g'(x) \;\;\;\Longrightarrow \;\;\;f(x) = g(x)+C,$$
it suffices to show 
$$h'(x) = 0 \;\;\;\Longrightarrow \;\;\;h(x)=C$$
for each differentiable function $h:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ .

Argue by contrapositive, without the loss of generality suppose there exist two points such that 
$$h(x_1) < h(x_2) \text{ for } a\leq x_1 < x_2 \leq b.$$
Apply mean value theorem on the subinterval $[x_1, x_2]$, there should exist a point $x\in (x_1, x_2)$ such that 
$$h'(x) = \frac{h(x_2) - h(x_1)}{x_2 - x_1} \neq 0.$$

Edit: I was wondering if there is a simpler proof without contrapositive and mean value theorem, like playing around with the definition and limits, maybe something that I am not seeing.

Edit2: Okay, thank you for letting me know that this is the standard proof. I thought there had to be an easier version like from high school calculus class.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: The proof is correct, and it is the standard proof.